Setting the 4337 Module on deployment?
Since the 4337 Module is also a fallbackHandler, we are using a proxy factory to deploy new Safe's, thus couldn't we set the fallbackHandler address to the deployed Safe4337Module address?

and thanks for the additional information.
What you want to achieve is possible, but we don't have official documentation for it. So here is how you can set the Safe4337Module as the fallbackhandler and a module at the Safe Proxy deployment.
You can use our utility contract SafeModuleSetup.
Here is example code on how you can get the date for the setup call (source).
const getInitializerCode = async ({
  owner,
  safeModuleSetupAddress,
  safe4337ModuleAddress,
  multiSendAddress,
  erc20TokenAddress,
  paymasterAddress,
}: {
  owner: Address
  safeModuleSetupAddress: Address
  safe4337ModuleAddress: Address
  multiSendAddress: Address
  erc20TokenAddress: Address
  paymasterAddress: Address
}) => {
  const setupTxs: InternalTx[] = [
    {
      to: safeModuleSetupAddress,
      data: enableModuleCallData(safe4337ModuleAddress),
      value: 0n,
      operation: 1, // 1 = DelegateCall required for enabling the module
    },
  ]

  if (erc20TokenAddress != zeroAddress && paymasterAddress != zeroAddress) {
    setupTxs.push({
      to: erc20TokenAddress,
      data: generateApproveCallData(paymasterAddress),
      value: 0n,
      operation: 0, // 0 = Call
    })
  }

  const recipient = setupTxs.length > 1 ? multiSendAddress : safeModuleSetupAddress
  const calldata = setupTxs.length > 1 ? encodeMultiSend(setupTxs) : setupTxs[0].data

  return encodeFunctionData({
    abi: SAFE_SETUP_ABI,
    functionName: 'setup',
    args: [[owner], 1n, recipient, calldata, safe4337ModuleAddress, zeroAddress, 0n, zeroAddress],
  })
}

As you can see here, the SafeModuleSetup is not deployed on many chains. So feel free to deploy it yourself using this deployment script.
I hope you manage to find your way around this. There will be a more official documentation about this feature soon, so I hope this gets you unblocked.

Yes, we have a proxy factory that deploys new proxy safes. We set the fallbackHandler to the deployed contract address, but we want to enable the Safe4337Module on deployment. How is that done exactly? I was thinking on setting the fallbackHandler in the setup function to the deployed Safe4337Module. If not, how to I use the to and from to set this up in the initializer so a new safe is has the Safe4337Module enabled in one transaction?

Hey @Dallascat, I editted the answer with more information. I hope this gets you unblocked. Let me know if it helps.

Thanks!! I have not seen the SafeModuleSetup contract before, this is helpful! I assume I could use this for other modules as well? We want to do this in Solidity, is there any example code in a Solidity contract that calls the setup function while deploying the Safe? I know in the initalizer there is the to and from that would be utilized, correct?

Sorry we currently don't have code examples in Solidity. You would have to take the example call from my answer and migrate it from TS to Solidity. Let me know if you encounter further issues. (Also, it would be nice if you could mark the question as answered.)

Thank you! Marked as answered :-)
